# Bootstrap modal animations don't work on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I can't see bootstrap modal animations while on other PC I can. I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 and Chrome version is 81.0.4044.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I have 'modal fade' as my modal class

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
dconf reset -f /
```

did the job...